# Academic papers for the pros and cons of password based system and digital signature with challenge and response system

Tags: signature, random-number-generator, passwords, ed25519, challenge-response

I don't really know what should be the correct title for this and the community can correct it after reading.

I was the author of PKDSA (Searchable on github).

I have the idea to do it because I feel like shifting from a password based scheme to challenge and respond with digital signature as much as possible might be good in the long run.

I would like to ask for help from the community in providing understandable or technical academic papers regarding CRNG, passwords, challenge and response mechanism, elliptic curves , digital signature and memory safety (only involves with immediate clearing of cryptographical sensitive data).

The algorithms that involved in the project are Blake2B, ED25519 and ED448.

The project strictly uses CRNG (Cryptographic random number generator, in my specific case, I am referring to any deterministic random number generator that has a similar structure as shown in computerphile's elliptic curve backdoor video) and mutable data types.

If there's academic papers which show how they work, their pros and cons in either brief or technical. It would greatly help because due to the some personal reasons, I may need to use this project as my FYP in my university and it turns out for this project to be used as FYP.... They only accept academic based references and the most common form of references are either journal or papers.

Comment: what is CRNG? define in your question, there are many definitions of generators and it needs to be clear and specific.

Comment: I slightly edited the question.

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify the question a bit. Concisely, what is the problem to be solved? What options are considered to solve this issue?